# How to redirect browser to a page from a database

Tags: php, redirect

I know how to redirect using the "refresh" meta tag in HTML. My webhost (Bluehost) also looks for an 404.SHTML page in case of a file not found. It seems to ignore a 404.PHP, however.

I want to intercept invalid URLs in my domain, and redirect to a corresponding page I look up in a database. A bit like bit.ly and other abbreviators do.

Since I need access to a database I figured to use PHP, but like I said my webhost only supports HTML for 404 messages.

Example: a user types in "example.net/123", where the directory 123 does not exist. So I want to look up "123" in my database, and it gives "foo.php" as corresponding page, so the user gets redirected to "example.net/foo.php". 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I did. First I redirected the mandatory 404.shtml to my own 404.php page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://mydomain.com/404.php";
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body></html>
```

Apparently there's no need to pass the referer since even without doing that 404.php will see the original referer, not 404.shtml. Very convenient. So all I have to do is look up the new url in the database. This is my 404.php:

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    //extract the reference from the url
    $abbrev= substr($url, 20, 1000);

    $username="********";
    $password="********";
    $database="********";
    mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("unable to select database");

    $query="SELECT * FROM fwd WHERE abbrev =" . $abbrev;                
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $url = mysql_result($result, $i, "url");
    header('Location: ' . $url);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>redirect</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course I have to check whether the abbreviation is in the database, and display a 404 message if it isn't (that's why the html code is still there), but this is the basic setup